# What's the refiner badge all about?

Tags: discussion, badges

Before I zealously go editing questions after my next answer upvote, can I confirm that my understanding of this badge (and the gold and bronze variants thereof) are correct:

> Edited 50 questions within 12 hours of posting a positive-scoring answer

This sounds quite a mouthful. I can't remember (ever) editing 50 questions in a 12 hour period. And why the correlation with a positive scoring answer?

(My first thought was that Winterbash had started early! But this was a badge, not a hat ...)

Comment: See [New three-tiered badge idea: New three-tiered badge idea: Explainer -> Refiner -> Illuminator](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239898)

Comment: Seems to be a new one. You've been just jumping in with this meta-question, when I received it, and wondered about. THX for clarification.

Comment: I got an `Explainer` today. Getting there!

Answer (score 146, accepted):

I think a less-confusing wording would be:

> Do the following 50 times: Edit a question within 12 hours of posting a positive-scoring answer to it

Comment: Much better! With all the crappy edits around, I'd _hate_ to see people try to edit 50 questions as fast as possible, just to get a badge!

Comment: @S.L.Barth .. imagine how people trying to get Illuminator would act then..... 500 edits in 12 hours.... ouch

Comment: Aha - got it. Perfect for OCD types like myself.

Comment: @StuartLC happy to have been of help. Honestly when I first read the badge I though exactly as you did and then I looked at illuminator and just jumped, thinking "I need to do 40 something edits AN HOUR for half a day????"... which is when I realized it HAD to be the other way around :P

Comment: Better than what's there, but still offers the same potential for misinterpretation. Going with, "Edited and answered 500 questions (both actions within 12 hours, answer score > 0)"

Comment: So if I got this right - Let's say XYZ posts a question. I answer it and get a positive score. So I've got 12 hours to edit the question posted by XYZ. Is that right? And if yes, I can't seem to imagine what could be the use of that?

Comment: @asprin to me, it seems like the point is, the system will reward you for being able to both answer a question well, and know how to improve a question. Or, another reason could be to realize you answered a poor question well, and also improved the question for other people.

Comment: @asprin I think by doing so, you improve on the general quality on SO (giving a good answer to a meh question, then changing the question to be good). So they try to reward the behavior of "making the site a better place"

Comment: @Shog9 What, you writing for programmers to understand or something?  :p

Answer (score 67):

Lesson learned: **don't write copy before coffee!**

[image: Edited and answered X question(s) (both actions within 12 hours, answer score > 0)]

Changes building out now...

Comment: _@Shog9_ _"Lesson learned: **don't write copy before coffee!**"_ `/OT Seems my current avatar pic becomes relevant again ;) /OT`

Comment: Too many stupid things to do, not enough hours in the day...

Comment: This could easily interpreted as having to edit and answer 500 questions within 12 hours. I understand what you mean because I read this, but not sure its what we're going for...

Comment: I'll probably spend less time explaining what "both" means than I would having to explain why editing doesn't count if you do it a year late, @BradleyDotNET. Most badge descriptions are prone to misinterpretation in some way - or straight-up omit criteria.

Comment: True enough. Its certainly better than it was.

Comment: @Shog9 TBH I saw the "both" version today for the first time, and it was a bit confusing to me in the same way. However when I saw `500` I realized that this interpretation doesn't have much sense (would mean question and answer every 1,5 minutes) ;)

Comment: Glad to have community moderators who are human (and admit it)!  Thanks for making the effort and dealing with us lot and our pitchforks from time to time.

Comment: i think this wording is equally confusing. How about "Edited a question after posting an answer with a score > 0. (50 times)" or something like that?

Comment: @sgroves: Yeah... I got here because as it is right now it's very confusing yet.

Comment: Is the upvote required before or after the edit? Is the upvote required within the 12 hour range?

Comment: **Edited a Question within 12 hours of posting a positively-scored Answer fot it, 50 times**

Comment: Same ambiguity, @Tshepang.

Comment: It's not *an upvote* that's required, @Claus - it's a positively-scored answer. If, at any time, the conditions for the badge are met, the badge will be awarded. The answer could meet these conditions by getting upvoted immediately, getting upvoted 2 years later, getting a downvote + two upvotes... Doesn't matter, as long as there are *N* of them at some point in time and the badge-award task runs.

Answer (score 25):

From the original idea post [New three-tiered badge idea: Explainer →Refiner → Illuminator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239898/new-three-tiered-badge-idea-keeper-archivist-curator):

> Let's say that you answer something, *and*:
>
> - You edit the question 12 hours before or after answering it. This allows you to edit now, answer later - or answer now and edit later,
>   when you have the time.
> - Your edit isn't rolled back, or outright rejected if it was a suggested edit
> - The question is not closed for any reason, even simply being a duplicate
> - Your answer has a score of 1 or higher
>
> ... then you've done something that we probably want to recognize. You
> understood something, you provided the knowledge that you have, and
> then you provided an *edit* to make sure that more people in need of
> this knowledge can find it, while raising the overall quality of the
> site.

Starting with just 1 such edit for the new *Explainer* badge, *Refiner* means you have 50 such answers where you edited the question, and there is also a gold *Illuminator* badge at 500 answers.

Shog posted the [final requirements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/240302/140890):

> Edited *n* questions within 12 hours of posting an answer (that's 12
> hours before *or* after answering), where:
>
> - The question was asked by someone other than the answerer
> - Neither the questions nor the answers are deleted
> - The questions are not closed
> - The answers score > 0
> - The question edits changed either body, titles, or both
>
> If *n* >= 1, [an Explainer badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4368/explainer) (bronze) is awarded.
>
> If *n* >= 50, [a Refiner badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4369/refiner) (silver) is awarded.
>
> If *n* >= 500, [an Illuminator badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4370/illuminator) (gold) is awarded.
>
> Each badge can be awarded only once per person, per site.

I created a set of SEDE queries to track stats and progress on these badges:

- [Illuminator badge progress](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/228743/illuminator-badge-progress) to track how many qualifying answers you have
- [Top Illuminators](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/228741/top-illuminators), the top badge holders by qualifying posts.
- [Most effective Illuminators](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/229980/most-effective-illuminators) - Illuminator badge holders ranked by weighted qualifying answers (count * percentage of total answers)
- [List all answers that count for the Illuminator badge](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/229690/list-all-answers-that-count-for-the-illuminator-badge) - Date-sorted list of qualifying answers

Comment: OMG! By this measure, I'm actually _ahead of Jon Skeet_:-)

Comment: @JohnSaunders: I was as surprised as you are. :-)

Comment: Great queries! Building on your [Most effective Illuminators](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/229980/most-effective-illuminators) query, I added some simplifications, rounded numbers and added an accept rate: [Most effective Illuminators with accept rate](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/235493/most-effective-illuminators-with-accept-rate).

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: cool, will study that tonight. If queries like these interest you, take a look at http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/116016/users-with-top-answer-effectiveness-accepted-percentage-times-quantity as well.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: The simplification of casting the original Count column to float is gratefully nicked and added to my version, as is the rounding! :-)

Comment: Nice. Here is one you might like: Comparing answers of two users for same questions. Example for you & me: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/235511/compare-answers-of-two-users-for-same-questions?OtherUserId=939860&UserId=100297 - but we only have a single question in common. A more interesting example: you & abarnert: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/235511/compare-answers-of-two-users-for-same-questions?OtherUserId=908494&UserId=100297

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: lots to like, and learn!

Comment: @MartijnPieters My mind is blown away. How does somebody **physically** answer 500 questions in 12h? *How did you guys did it?*

Comment: @UmNyobe: you misunderstand the badge. You don't need to write 500 answers in one 12 hour sitting. For every answer that you make, you need to have edited the question you answered as well, within 12 hours of answering (or 12 hours before you posted the answer). That time window applies *per answer*.

Comment: @UmNyobe: those 500 qualifying answers (they also must have a score greater than 0, so at least one upvote) can be posted whenever.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for the explanation. still very impressive.

Comment: @UmNyobe: for example, I have [more than 2600 answers that qualify](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/229690/list-all-answers-that-count-for-the-illuminator-badge?UserId=100297), but they were posted over a long period of time.