# Why does the vote count on my profile's tags not update?

Tags: bug, tags, voting, profile-page

This is what my profile vote count per tag on Stack Overflow since last Monday

[image: tags]

It should be more than that because I got more up votes since then. Why don't these values update?

Comment: The standard answer to these types of questions is normally "it's caching". Let's see if you get the same answer here... These numbers typically seem to update about once a day. But I've also seen it take at least 2 days. Including now.

Comment: It's stuck again for the past two days. I blame the [new badges](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272535).

Comment: It's not the first time things got stuck. Related: [Can I haz stinkin' silver tag badge, plz?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253587)

Comment: So is this a bug in `stackOverflow`? kind of a update(data base) job failure ?

Comment: See also here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226681/tag-scores-are-not-updated-and-the-issue-is-getting-worse. It hasn't updated for about 4 days now. I had never noticed it being stuck for *this* long.

Comment: @RetoKoradi 3 days later... still no update :( (7+ days without any update)

Comment: Now it is more than a week. No solution... No reason... Not nice.

Comment: There is a downvoter for the question. He may know the answer for this.

Comment: Naturally this happens the week I qualify for the gold Python badge. I want my dupe hammer :(

Comment: I suppose my stats have been stuck for more than 1.5 weeks, I'd like to know if they will ever be recounted again..

Comment: It's alive! Counts have updated.

Comment: Yes it is working again

Comment: It worked last night, lets see if it'll *keep* working. :-) Congrats @dano, welcome to the hammer club! Feel free to join the [python chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) to find out about exiting DIY projects! :-)

Comment: It worked and received gold `Java` badge.

Comment: Seems like the tags in Stack Overflow (Top users in question tag, Tags in the Profile) had not been updated since the week of 11 December 2023.

Answer (score 12):

There are previous threads on MSE discussing this problem:

- [Can I haz stinkin' silver tag badge, plz?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253587/can-i-haz-stinkin-silver-tag-badge-plz)
- [Tag scores are not updated and the issue is getting worse](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226681/tag-scores-are-not-updated-and-the-issue-is-getting-worse)

Based on a comment by Martijn on one of those older posts, the counts should update once a day:

> The badge awarding is normally part of the tag-score calculations, which runs once a day (at 03:00 UTC)

The answers and comments on those questions suggest that the job that is supposed to update the counts times out on a fairly regular basis. This is consistent with my own observations. The counts typically change in the evening my local time (PDT), but they sometimes don't.

I had never noticed the counts being stuck for as long as right now, though. I believe they haven't updated all week, which would be around 4 days by now, and counting.

A new report for the current instance of this problem was also posted on MSE yesterday:

- [Reputation for tags has been stuck for 3 days on SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240535/reputation-for-tags-has-been-stuck-for-3-days-on-so)

This was closed as a duplicate of the old reports, where the only answer (which has a negative score) suggested that it's not a serious problem. My interpretation of this is that the delayed tag score updates are considered a know problem, with no plans of addressing it.

Comment: This has happened at least once before, it took over a week for them to fix it. I believe the relevant bug is now on Meta SE.

Comment: It has been several days now that none of my tags are updated.

Comment: @VonC Yes, still no updates. The main reason I posted this answer yesterday was to try and give the problem some more attention/upvotes. Well, and because a very valid question deserves *some* kind of answer, even if I wasn't able to provide a great deal of insight.

Comment: I am afraid , why the SE employees failed to fix this problem which prevails over a week...

Comment: @AvinashRaj: because the problem is a tough one to crack.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Considering it's been originally reported months ago before, I'd have expected a little update from the dev team (even if it's sort of "we are aware, still working on it").

Comment: @BlueMoon: the team is aware of it, at some point Nick Craver was going to look into it, then the problem went away for quite a while. It only resurfaced last week after a long hiatus, so I assumed Nick *had* looked into it and made changes.

Comment: @Reto Koradi, is this issue still exists today? I have seen a mis-match of 15 score ( 70 instead 55) for one of my tags. : design-patterns