# Mismatch in tag count in profile

Tags: bug, tags

I see a huge mismatch between tag score count and actual score of a tag.

My [profile page score](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4999394/ravindra-babu) for the [design-patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/design-patterns) tag: 55.

My [actual score](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a4999394%20%5bdesign-patterns%5d) of the [design-patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/design-patterns) tag: 70.

I know that a mismatch exists, but I do not see an end to this mismatch even after a week instead of days.

I have gone through an old question: [Why does the vote count on my profile's tags not update?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272647/why-does-the-vote-count-on-my-profiles-tags-not-update), but I am not sure if this issue still exists.

Does this issue still exist?

Comment: For your search, you'll want the "is:a" or "is:answer" parameter- Questions don't count for your score in a tag. (I suppose if you're paying attention you can manually exclude the question score, but it's easier to make them all answers.) As for why it's not correct, I'd assume it's just a hung job or the script not running.

Comment: I have only one question with score:5. So at least count should match with a score of  65

Comment: you have to take into account downvotes too, I believe...