# Which step of suggested edits counts for Explainer / Refiner / Illuminator badges?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, badges

I understand the +/- 12-hour window around posting the question (explained again here [What's the refiner badge all about?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272533/12846804))

Now what exactly is the considered time for editing the question?

1. time of suggesting an edit (provided the edit was approved by review)
2. time the edit was approved by review

Given that I am seeing my counter stuck at 3, I wonder if that is not the latter.
Another observation supporting the second option: Edition messages below posts ("Edited by ... at...") will mention time of approval.

If that is correct, the thing is, time of approval is beyond our control. Given the apparent chronic saturation of reviewing, doesn't this make this badge rather random?

Comment: Surely it's on accept side, as when the system is working correctly edits get accepted quickly, and edits that haven't been applied haven't had the positive effect the badge is meant to encourage.

Comment: "Given the apparent chronic saturation of reviewing" - hmm. This breaks my brain. Are you perhaps referring to the review queues here? I think what you want to say is that reviewing is on a decline - and so it can take a while for an edit to be approved.

Comment: @Gimby Yes, not knowing the review mechanisms, I am merely refering to how often the edition button is blocked because "too many pending edits".

Comment: @OCa ah yes, there is also that. That is specific to the pending edits though, not reviewing in general.

Answer (score 4):

It is based on when the edit is accepted/approved. See *[Delay in approval leads to missing out on being awarded an "Explainer" badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250777/delay-in-approval-leads-to-missing-out-on-being-awarded-an-explainer-badge)* from Meta Stack Exchange:

> [...] I then suggested an edit to the question at 17:03. However, it was not until 20 hours later, at 13:03, that the edit was approved, so I appear to have missed out on the "Explainer" badge, as the edit should be done within 12 hours. [...]

As you can see, it is counted when the edit is *applied* to the post (publicly), not when it is suggested.

> If that is correct, the thing is, time of acceptance is beyond our control. Given the apparent chronic saturation of reviewing, doesn't this make this badge rather random?

Having an answer upvoted is also beyond your control, directly. It's unfortunate that users below 2,000 reputation suffer from this higher burden. The silver lining is that, by the time you have written ~50 answers and suggested 50 edits (let alone 500/500), you'll (hopefully) be well on your way to 2,000 reputation, if not there already.

Comment: Ah, yes, thank you that reference makes it very clear. I should search Meta Stack Exchange as well for these questions, not only Stack Overflow Meta. So adapting badge algorithm due to his issue was already considered a few years ago.